# How do I monitor the records in my SQLite DB while developing an Android App

Tags: android, sqlite

Im developing an android app and Im using a local SQLite database for testing purposes.
How do I know what are the contents of that DB? How do I view the records?

For example I've just inserted a new user. How do I know they are there?

Comment: When you could insert a row, you could also query the table I suppose.  So, get the cursor and getCount from it if its not null.

Comment: so I have to take some dummy actions inside of my application in order to view the database contents? isnt there some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipe, you can open DDMS perspective while your emulator is on and later:

`File Explorer` -> `data` -> `data` -> `app package name` -> `databases`

Your app database should be inide `databases` folder. Select your database and push or pull the database with the two buttons on the upper tab. You can open your database file with [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) Firefox extension to check the records in your database.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed!!!!! Will try it and will write a comment if I need some clarification. (btw I use my real device, dunno if this makes any difference)

Comment: If you're using your real device, you need to have root access, and run adb in root mode (using "adb root").

Comment: well I dont have root access, I suppose. Damn it.

Comment: can I use my emulator whenever I want to see the database and my device whenever I need to test functionality? or the DBs are different?

Comment: the databases will be different.